# Python re - running a program from the top without while

Tags: python, performance

I wanted to ask, 

 Is there a way that you can re - run any sort of program on Python 3.x or 2.x without the need for a while loop?

For instance, is there any block of code that I can use to do this:

```
if user says yes:
    re - run code from top
else:
    end program
```

For instance, take this example:

```
output Hello what would you like to do?
     if user says internet
           response = go to internet.
     if response = true
           go to start.
     else
           end program

def internet
     open web page.
     output Would you like to do anything else?
     if input is yes
          return True
     else
          return False
```

Thanks, 
Judy.

Note, the code above is a mock - up.

Comment: What wrong with `while user says yes:`? Also python does not have the `GOTO` statement

Comment: That is the typical use/case for functions: Wrap your functionality in one and put the user-interaction inside your `main()`.

Comment: are you referring to @loli `if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()`

Comment: Yes, that is the one I mean.

Comment: Yes, but python has `continue`, which for a loop is `GOTO` the start -- which is roughly what the OP wants.  then make a `for` loop where you ask the user for (raw)`input`.

Comment: @WallyBeaver thank you very much sir! If you could write your reponse as an answer too, I will gladly tick your answer and accept it! I have tested it on my mock program and it works ever so well! Please respond to my question! Thanks a million sir!

Comment: Is there a reason you are ruling out a while loop? You appear to know how to do this, but for some reason don't want to use it?

Answer (score 3):

This works...

```
>>> from itertools import count
>>> c = count()
>>> for i in c:
...   i = input("what is your input? ")
...   if str(i) == "internet":
...     print "internet"
...   elif i == True:
...     continue
...   else:
...     break
... 
what is your input? True
what is your input? "internet"
internet
what is your input? "foo"
>>>
```

But it's still much better as a `while` loop.

Comment: True, it's answers the question. But it's very purpose-defeating and unclear code to use an infinite iterator to run an infinite loop. And re-using `i` is equally bad style.

Comment: @loli: agreed.  Using `while` is the better choice here... I would not use my own code above over while for any reason I can think of -- as noted in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `while` is actually the best and cleanest solution here. Remember to place all re-usable functionality in functions or classes. E.g.:

```
def main():
    while True:
        fun()
        ask user
        if user says no:
            break

def fun():
    # your functionality goes here

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while user says no:
    if user says yes:
        do stuff
        break
```

This gets rid of one of the statements.

Answer (score -1):

You can restart the execution of a script with [os.exec*()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.execl)

Hope this helps!

Comment: That is a possible, but not very good way to handle the situation. Messing with the processes is potentially dangerous and makes following the codes execution order very difficult.

Comment: wait, so inside the parentheses, would I have to include the file directory?

Comment: I agree that I wouldn't find a use for this but it is still it's purpose none the less.

Comment: Well, in that case recursion will be a better option - actually, what you suggest is recursion - with subshell thrown in - and the latter is a very bad idea. Too much system resources to run

Comment: That wasn't the question though.